# Не понимаю как работают mime-типы в xfce

Tags: linux, xubuntu, mime, xfce, mime-type

Смотрите, вот у меня есть 2 совершенно разных mime-типа: `text/markdown` и `text/plain`. На скриншоте в терминале хорошо видно, что они разные и в mime-редакторе для каждого из них установлено отдельное приложение - Firefox для md и Textadept для текста. Но почему-то файловый менеджер так не считает. Он говорит что .md файл - это kind of text/plain и когда я прошу его открыть .md браузером, он и все остальные текстовые файлы начинает открывать браузером. Как же мне объяснить файловому менеджеру, что он не прав?

[image: Скриншот]

---

@Fat-Zer `exo-info` и `gnomevfs-info` в xubuntu нет, но есть `exo-open` и да, он ведёт себя так же.

Вот вывод grep для `~/.config/*mimeapps.list`:

```
[23:47:59] luarocks@MAINFRAME /home/luarocks  
> grep "text/plain" ~/.config/*mimeapps.list
text/plain=menulibre-textadept.desktop
text/plain=firefox.desktop;me.mitya57.ReText.desktop;code.desktop;menulibre-textadept.desktop;mousepad.desktop;
[23:48:46] luarocks@MAINFRAME /home/luarocks  
> grep "text/markdown" ~/.config/*mimeapps.list
text/markdown=firefox.desktop
text/markdown=code.desktop;exo-web-browser.desktop;firefox.desktop;
```

Я пробовал поправить `~/.config/mimeapps.list` как мне нужно, он сохраняется без проблем, но это ничего не дало.

После моих правок он теперь выглядит примерно так:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=code.desktop;menulibre-textadept.desktop;
text/markdown=code.desktop;firefox.desktop;

[Added Associations]
text/plain=code.desktop;menulibre-textadept.desktop;
text/markdown=code.desktop;firefox.desktop;
```

`gio info readme.md` выдаёт неверные типы:

```
attributes:
  standard::type: 1
  standard::name: readme.md
  standard::display-name: readme.md
  standard::edit-name: readme.md
  standard::copy-name: readme.md
  standard::icon: text-plain, text-x-generic, text-plain-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic
  standard::content-type: text/plain
  standard::fast-content-type: text/plain
  standard::size: 1607
  standard::allocated-size: 4096
  standard::symbolic-icon: text-plain-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, text-plain, text-x-generic
```

---

Похоже я понял в чём причина!

Когда я устанавливал [вот это](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/markdown-viewer-webext) расширение для Firefox, чтобы просматривать .md файлы браузером, там была проблема в том, что вместо отображения файлов браузер предлагал их **скачать**. И на сайте расширения была [инструкция](https://github.com/KeithLRobertson/markdown-viewer/blob/master/README.md#support-for-local-files-on-linux), которую я выполнил и это стало решением проблемы фаерфокса, но породило данную проблему.

Простите что я совсем забыл об этом.

Я не знаю что тут делать. Видимо в моём случае действительно лучшим выходом будет не менять базу mime, а просто написать скрипт конкретно для md.

Большое спасибо Fat-Zer за то что помог мне выявить причину!

Comment: вопрос вообще-то не про xfce, а про конкретную (неназванную вами) программу, которую вы определили как «файловый менеджер».

Comment: `exo-info` ведёт себя также как и ФМ? в `grep . ~/.config/*mimeapps.list` всё корректно сохраняется? какой mime для файла выдаёт `gnomevfs-info`? а `gnomevfs-info --slow-mime`?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это стандартный файловый менеджер, входящий в состав xfce. Он называется thunar.

Comment: @Fat-Zer я обновил вопрос.

Comment: В общем, если у кого-то есть догадки, в чём тут причина - пишите, буду признателен. Но если нет, то ладно, я напишу скрипт, который будет обрабатывать файл по расширению, хотя это конечно жуткий костыль.

Comment: да, имел в виду `exo-open`...  В каких оно секциях/файлах в `mimeapps.list`? определяемый mime-тип можешь посмотреть `gio info …` … или `xdg-mime query filetypeм …` на крайняк... если `mimeapps.list` окажется некорректным, то скорей всего это баг в конфигурашке... а если тип некорректно определяется, то скорей всего mime-база почему-то оказалась битая — нужно будет её перегенерировать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer дополнил вопрос. Подскажи пожалуйста, как перегенерировать базу?

Comment: @Fat-Zer погодь, я понял в чём причина! Сейчас дополню вопрос :)

Comment: @Fat-Zer готово.

Comment: нуда... ССЗБ... почему бы просто не прописать это в файле из `helpers.private_mime_types_file`, как там вторым вариантом рекомендуется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer по-моему он делает то же самое - назначает расширению .md тип text/plain... Ну это уже не важно. Я доволен тем, что у меня по крайней мере с базой и остальными типами всё в порядке. Спасибо :)

Comment: в огнелисе можно задать другой `helpers.private_mime_types_file` и использовать отдельные mime-типы только для него, а не калечить их для всей системы... +AFAIK {/etc/,~/.}mime_types не используются в спецификациях FDO, так что большинство DE эти изменения не должны затронуть...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, действительно! Это самое простое и правильное решение. Можешь скопировать его в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку моя проблема очень специфическая, то и решил я её специфическим способом - отдельным лаунчером и lua-скриптом (простите что не баш и не питон, я люблю луа ).

Вряд ли кому-то будет полезно моё решение, но пожалуй опубликую его, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

**~/.local/share/applications/run-file.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run file
Comment=Run file
Type=Application
Exec=run-file.sh %f
Icon=system-run
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
```

**run-file.sh**

```
#!/bin/luajit

local file = arg[1]

local ext = string.find(file, "%.")

if ext then
  ext = string.sub(file, ext+1, -1)
end

if ext == "md" then
  os.execute("firefox " .. file)
else
  os.execute("textadept " .. file)
end
```